# How to install Oracle 11g Express 64bit in a 32bit system?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to ubuntu/linux I want to install Oracle 11g Express with 32bit Intel system which is dual boot with win7. I am following apt-get installation process using:

[Link to installation process](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.in/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html)

At STEP 4 I am executing command:

```
sudo alien --scripts -d /home/sysadmin/Downloads/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

And getting this error:

> /home/sysadmin/Downloads/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm is for
>   architecture amd64 ; the package cannot be built on this system

How to resolve this error?
Is my version of oracle (oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm) proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle only provides Express Edition downloads for 32-bit Windows, or 64-bit Linux.  You will not be able to get the x86_64 version to work on 32-bit Ubuntu.

Your options are:

- Install the Win-32 version on your Win7 partition.
- Install the [Oracle 11g *Enterprise* Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) (which does have a 32-bit Linux version)
- Install Oracle 10g Express Edition (which also has a 32-bit Linux version)

I don't think 10g is being actively distributed by Oracle anymore, but [here is a site where someone still has a link to the 32-bit version of 10g](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2013/03/installing-oracle-xe-on-ubuntu-32-bit.html).  I can't speak to how much longer it will be available (as the file is on this person's Ubuntu One drive), but it should work for now.

For the Enterprise Edition, you can legally use it (for educational or evaluation purposes).  But you will not be able to get patches and updates for it without a license agreement with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

It means your 32-bit OS doesn't support the amd64 bit version of that software.

Try this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linuxsoft-085393.html